# Remove incomplete URL's

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file containing broken URL's like

```
 http images5fanpopcomimagephotos29000000ichigowallpaperkurosakiichigo290694271024768jpg
```

and

```
 https smediacacheak0pinimgcomoriginals1219ed1219ed717fc2bfce372759bba2fe1cfegif
```

. I want to remove these long strings coming after http or https.

Can someone suggest a solution ?

Comment: You can't make a generic regex for that. You need to analyze correct URLs and make a regex for each (or the most possible). We will most likely not be doing the research for you, as this should be the first thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I will look into it , just needed a starting hint !!

Comment: What programming language are you using ?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: I'm not programming with Python, but try the following regex, it will match the broken URL's like you provided `(http|https)\s.+`

Answer (score -1):

You could search each line for http or https and then if the line is longer than X (e.g. 40) characters and has no "/" and/or "." in it, delete.

```
System.IO.StringReader strReader = new System.IO.StringReader(input);
string line;
string output;
while ((line = strReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  if(line.IndexOf("http") == 0)
  {
    if( (line.Length >40) && ((line.Contains('.') == false) || (line.Contains('/') == false)) )
      {
        add = false;
      } else {
        add = true;
      }
    } else {
      add = true
    }
  if(add)   output += line + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Be warned that code was just written here and not tested so could have a bug or two, but the concept is there.

Comment: he is using python, he said it in the comments + there's a tag for it in the question

Comment: Both the comment and the tag were added after my post. I put a C# example in as his question started out as more conceptual than language specific. For Python one can use
    strReader = StringIO.StringIO(input)
    strReader.readline()
instead of the StringReader.